# How to create a scatterplot using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot using values TPR_FPR on y axis and H/M on x axis.

```
Score_desc 

         H/M         TPR_FPR
  0.22463089     0.003115265
 -0.12983744     0.8660436
  0.52798131     0.8722741
  0.71147136     0.003115265
```

I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(Score_desc, aes(x=H/M, y=TPR_FPR)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=23) +
  labs(x="log2(H/M)", y="TPR_FPR", title=NULL) +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="right")
```

Something similar to this:

[image]

What plot type would be the most suitable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Score_desc, aes(x=H_M, y=TPR_FPR)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=23) +
  geom_line()+
  labs(x="log2(H/M)", y="TPR_FPR", title=NULL) +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="right") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0)+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]
Data

```
Score_desc = structure(list(H_M = c(0.22463089, -0.12983744, 0.52798131, 0.71147136
), TPR_FPR = c(0.003115265, 0.8660436, 0.8722741, 0.003115265
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```